# How to make a SQLAlchemy query return instances of the model class?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I understand that there are (at least) two ways to query a database: Using `<Model>.query` or using `db.session.query(SomeMappedClass)`.  When I tried both, the first gave me results as instances of the model class, and the second gave me instances of `sqlalchemy.util._collections.result`.

How can I make the second way of querying give me results as instances of the model class like the first does?

```
>>> Widget.query.first()
<Widget title='Widget 0' uuid='90eca137-1426-43c7-b5e4-2225de5abd0a' user_id=1 deleted=False>

>>> type(_)
models.sql_models.Widget

>>> db.session.query(table).first()
(1, 'Widget 0', '90eca137-1426-43c7-b5e4-2225de5abd0a', 1, False)

>>> type(_)
sqlalchemy.util._collections.result
```

Comment: The second way bypasses the ORM, so it doesn't know that there's a class related to the table you're querying. You could probably create a `Widget` object from the returned tuple `Widget(*db.session.query(table).first())`, or you could re-phrase your query in terms of the ORM. I hope someone else has a more helpful answer, though.